# Restriccion por dia y mes sql

Tags: sql, oracle

El enunciado es el siguiente:
No hay partidos en verano (desde el 21/06 al 21/09) ni el día de Navidad ni el de
Año Nuevo.
Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE Partidos(
    codigo number(5),
    fecha date,
    codigo_visitante number(5),
    codigo_local number(5),

    CONSTRAINT pk_partido PRIMARY KEY (codigo),
    CONSTRAINT fk_codigo_local FOREIGN KEY (codigo_visitante) REFERENCES Equipos(codigo),
    CONSTRAINT fk_codigo_visitante FOREIGN KEY (codigo_local) REFERENCES Equipos(codigo)
);
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo crear un check donde compare la fecha con el dia y mes de un año X. Es decir, como podria hacer esto: CHECK(fecha!='25-09' AND fecha!='01-01'...).

PD: estoy dando solamente DDL asi que no es algo muy complejo la solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que con un `constraint` y `to_char` con `between` es suficiente. Acá te dejo el ejemplo de como debería ser el script:

```
CREATE TABLE PARTIDO
(
  CODIGO       NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
  FECHA        DATE NOT NULL,
  EQLOCAL      NUMBER(5) REFERENCES EQUIPO,
  EQVISITANTE  NUMBER(5) REFERENCES EQUIPO,
  CONSTRAINT FECHA_PARTIDOS
    CHECK (TO_CHAR(FECHA, 'MMDD') NOT BETWEEN '0621' AND '0921'),
  CONSTRAINT DIST_EQUIPOS
    CHECK (EQLOCAL <> EQVISITANTE)
);
```

Éxitos!

Comment: Solo para complementar dejo un [enlace a la documentación de la función `TO_CHAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) de Oracle y un [recurso adicional](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server/to_char_datetime) para comprender el uso de dicha función.